# Enlarging set where "weighted" MacLaurin series of $\frac{1}{1 - x}$ equals $\frac{1}{1 - x}$

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Is it possible to select real values $a_{n, k}$ so that

$$f(x) =\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} a_{n, k} x^k = \frac{1}{1 - x} $$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{1\}$ ?

Failing examples:

1. $a_{n, k} = 1$ for all $n, k \in \mathbb{N}_0$ and $\lvert x \rvert < 1$

$$f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} x^k = \frac{1}{1 - x}$$

2. $a_{n, k}  = 1 - \frac{k}{n}$ for all $n, k \in \mathbb{N}_0$ and $ x\in [-1, 1)$ (One extra point!)

$$\begin{aligned} f(x) &=\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} \left( 1 - \frac{k}{n}\right) x^k \\ &=\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} \left( 1 - \frac{k}{n}\right) x^k \\ 
&= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x (x^n-1)}{n (x-1)^2} + \frac{1}{1-x} \\ &= \frac{1}{1 - x}\end{aligned}$$

Comment: The Mac-Laurin series of $1/(1-x)$ evaluated at $y$ will have radius of convergence $|1-y|$, For example. $\sum_i b^{-i}x^i$ converges to $1/(b-x)$ while $|x|<b$. So $\sum_i b^{-i}(x+(b-1))^i$ converges to $1/(1-x)$ in a larger radius.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the [Stone-Weierstraß theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_approximation_theorem), we can uniformly approximate every continuous function on a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ by a sequence of polynomials.

Thus if we exhaust $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{1\}$ by a sequence of compact sets, say $K_m = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : 2^{-m} \leqslant \lvert x-1\rvert \leqslant 2^m\}$, and for each $m$ pick a polynomial $p_m$ such that

$$\sup \left\{ \biggl\lvert p_m(x) - \frac{1}{1-x}\biggr\rvert : x \in K_m\right\} \leqslant 2^{-m}$$

and $\deg p_{m+1} > \deg p_m$ for all $m$, we obtain a sequence of polynomials converging pointwise - even locally uniformly - to $\frac{1}{1-x}$ on $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{1\}$.

Letting $a_{n,k}$ the coefficients of $p_m$ for $\deg p_m < n \leqslant \deg p_{m+1}$, we then have

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k = 0}^{n-1} a_{n,k} x^k = \frac{1}{1-x}$$

for all $x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{1\}$ as desired.

However, I don't think one could call such a sequence a "weighted MacLaurin series" in any reasonable way. The coefficients of the $p_m$ have most likely very little to do with the coefficients of the Taylor/MacLaurin series of $\frac{1}{1-x}$.

Answer (score 0):

In order that our power sums match the Taylor series of $\frac{1}{1-x}$ in a neighbourhood of the origin we must have $\lim_{n\to +\infty}a_{n,k}=1$ for every $k$, so we cannot have convergence outside the unit disk.

Comment: You might be correct but this is not immediately clear to me. Could you be more specific? What if $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{k \in [n - 1]} \lvert a_{n, k} - 1 \rvert \not = 0$?

Comment: @Reactant: in such a case the series cannot converge to $\frac{1}{1-x}$ inside the unit disk - the Taylor series of $\frac{1}{1-x}$ is unique.